# How to connect to offline cube file in .NET 7

Tags: file, offline, cube

In .NET Framework 4.5 we could easily connect to Offline cube files with this code :

```
AdomdConnection conn = new AdomdConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source='e:\\xxx.cub';Integrated Security=SSPI";
conn.Open();
```

but in .NET 7 , We encounter an error :

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'This feature is not supported for a .NET Core client.'
```

is there any solution for this ?